# how to use splash screen to load main application( fxml and controllers )inside task without delay

Tags: java, javafx, splash-screen

So i'm still new to java an javafx. And for practical purpose i'm creating an application. It is becoming very large so i decided to create a splash screen. 
Inside the splash screen i load the database stuff. Once this is done i'm loading all the controllers who shows my main application.

But now after the splash screen the rootlayout is loaded instantly. But it still takes some time before the other controllers are loaded so i get this screen :

[image]

after 5 - 10 seconds all the stuff inside the screen is also loaded.

But now the question!

Is there a way to load the main app (like loading it invisible) And once it loaded show the main app and remove the splash screen.

This is my code of the splash screen

```
public class LoaderController implements Initializable {

    private Stage mainStage ;
    private Stage primaryStage ;
    public LoginController loginController ; 
    public UserDTO UserDTO;
    public CompanyDTO company;
    public ObservableList<CustomerDTO> listCustomers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();



    public ObservableList<String> listAllFriends;

     @FXML public ImageView image;
     @FXML public ProgressBar progressBarLoader;
     @FXML public Label labelProgress;
     @FXML public Label labelWelcome;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


    }   

        private void loadMainProgramTasks () throws SQLException {






               final Task<Void> friendTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override

            protected Void call() throws InterruptedException, SQLException, IOException {

                ObservableList<String> foundFriends =
                        FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList();

                ObservableList<String> availableFriends =
                        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                              /*  "Fili", "Kili", "Oin", "Gloin", "Thorin",
                                "Dwalin", "Balin", "Bifur", "Bofur",
                                "Bombur", "Dori", "Nori", "Ori"*/
                        );

                //Enter name process and methode
                availableFriends.add("DataBaseStuff");
                LoadCompanyFromDataBase();
                availableFriends.add("More dataBaseStuff");
                LoadAllCustomersFromDataBase();



                //This was my first solution but it gives following error :
                //java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
                  try {
                     ViewsMainAppController view = new ViewsMainAppController();
                  view.LoadMainStageViews(LoaderController.this);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println(e);
                }





                updateMessage("Loading application . . .");
                for (int i = 0; i < availableFriends.size(); i++) {
                   Thread.sleep(500);
                    updateProgress(i + 1, availableFriends.size());
                    String nextFriend = availableFriends.get(i);
                    foundFriends.add(nextFriend);
                    updateMessage("Loading applicationdata . . .  " + nextFriend);
                }
                Thread.sleep(400);
                updateMessage("All application stuff loaded.");

                listAllFriends = availableFriends;

                return null;
            }
        };





           showSplash(friendTask,() -> {
               try {
                   ViewsMainAppController view = new ViewsMainAppController();
                   view.LoadMainStageViews(this);
               } catch (IOException ex) {
                   System.out.println("Error Error !!" + ex);
               }

           });

        new Thread(friendTask).start();

    }


    private void showSplash (Task<?> task ,InitCompletionHandler initCompletionHandler) {

       labelProgress.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
       progressBarLoader.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        task.stateProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                progressBarLoader.progressProperty().unbind();
                progressBarLoader.setProgress(1);


               FadeTransition fadeSplash = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.2));
               fadeSplash.setFromValue(1.0);
               fadeSplash.setToValue(0.0);

              fadeSplash.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> loginController.loaderStage.hide());
              fadeSplash.play();

              initCompletionHandler.complete();

            } // todo add code to gracefully handle other task states.
        });

    }     


   public void setLoginProperties(LoginController loginController) throws SQLException {


        this.loginController = loginController ; 
        this.UserDTO = loginController.userDTO ;
        image.setImage( new Image(LoginConfigurations.SPLASH_IMAGE));

        loadMainProgramTasks();
    }



 public interface InitCompletionHandler {
        public void complete();
    }


      private void LoadCompanyFromDataBase () throws SQLException {

        CompanyDAO dao = new CompanyDAO();
        Connection conn = LocalConnection.getconnection();

        company = dao.selectCompany(conn);

     }

      public void LoadAllCustomersFromDataBase () throws SQLException {

        CustomerDAO dao = new CustomerDAO();
        Connection conn = LocalConnection.getconnection();

        listCustomers = dao.selectAllCustomers(conn);

     }



}
```

this is the code of ViewsMainAppController

```
public class ViewsMainAppController extends BorderPane{


    private Stage primaryStage;

    private LoaderController loaderController;

    //Main app controlers


    private TabPane tabPaneMain;
    private BorderPane borderPaneroot;
    private RootLayoutController rootLayoutController;

   public void setLoader(LoaderController loaderController) {
        this.loaderController = loaderController;       
        MyLogger.info("main app loaded");



    }

   public void LoadMainStageViews (LoaderController loadController ) throws IOException{




            setLoader(loadController);
            initRootLayout(loadController);
            showMainTab(loadController);
            showStartAnchorPane(loadController);
            showCustomersAnchorPane(loadController);
            showInvoiceAnchorPane(loadController);
            showOrderAnchorPane(loadController);
            showCreditNotaAnchorPane(loadController);
            showStatisticsAnchorPane(loadController);
            showSettingsAnchorPane(loadController);


   }

   public void initRootLayout(LoaderController loaderController) throws IOException {



            primaryStage = new Stage();

            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/RootLayout.fxml"));
            borderPaneroot = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPaneroot);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);



           rootLayoutController = loader.getController();

           rootLayoutController.setRootLayout2(loaderController,this);

            primaryStage.show();

    } 

   public void showMainTab(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load mainTab overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/MainTab.fxml"));
            tabPaneMain = (TabPane) loader.load();
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);

           MainTabController controller = loader.getController();
           controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController,this);


       } catch (IOException e) {
           MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showMainTab : " + e);
       }
    }

   public void showStartAnchorPane(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load mainTab overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/StartPage.fxml"));
            AnchorPane StartAnchorPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set StartAnchorPane overview into mainTab.

            Tab startTab = new Tab("Start pagina", StartAnchorPane);
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);
            tabPaneMain.getTabs().add(startTab);

            StartPageController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController,this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
             MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showStartAnchorPane : " + e);
        }
    }


   public void showCustomersAnchorPane(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load mainTab overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/CustomersTab.fxml"));
            AnchorPane customersAnchorPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set tab

            Tab startTab = new Tab("klanten", customersAnchorPane);
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);
            tabPaneMain.getTabs().add(startTab);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            CustomersTabController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController,this);


        } catch (IOException e) {
             MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showStartAnchorPane : " + e);
        }
    }



   public void showInvoiceAnchorPane(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load  overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/InvoiceTab.fxml"));
            AnchorPane invoiceAnchorPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set StartAnchorPane overview into Tab.
            Tab startTab = new Tab("Facturen", invoiceAnchorPane);
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);
            tabPaneMain.getTabs().add(startTab);


             // Give the controller access to the main app.
            InvoiceTabController  controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController ,this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
             MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showStartAnchorPane : " + e);
        }
    }

        public void showOrderAnchorPane(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load  overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/OrderTab.fxml"));
            AnchorPane OrderTab = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set StartAnchorPane overview into Tab.
            Tab startTab = new Tab("BestelBon", OrderTab);
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);
            tabPaneMain.getTabs().add(startTab);


             // Give the controller access to the main app.
            OrderTabController  controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController);



        } catch (IOException e) {
             MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showStartAnchorPane : " + e);
        }
    }

        public void showCreditNotaAnchorPane(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load  overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/CreditnotaTab.fxml"));
            AnchorPane CreditnotaTab = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set StartAnchorPane overview into Tab.
            Tab startTab = new Tab("Creditnota", CreditnotaTab);
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);
            tabPaneMain.getTabs().add(startTab);


             // Give the controller access to the main app.
            CreditnotaTabController  controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController);



        } catch (IOException e) {
             MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showStartAnchorPane : " + e);
        }
    }
        public void showStatisticsAnchorPane(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load  overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/StatisticsTab.fxml"));
            AnchorPane OrderTab = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set StartAnchorPane overview into Tab.
            Tab StatisticsTab = new Tab("Statistics", OrderTab);
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);
            tabPaneMain.getTabs().add(StatisticsTab);


             // Give the controller access to the main app.
            StatisticsTabController  controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController);



        } catch (IOException e) {
             MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showStartAnchorPane : " + e);
        }
    }
        public void showSettingsAnchorPane(LoaderController loaderController) {
        try {
            // Load  overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/fxml/SettingsTab.fxml"));
            AnchorPane SettingsTab = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set StartAnchorPane overview into Tab.
            Tab startTab = new Tab("Settings", SettingsTab);
            borderPaneroot.setCenter(tabPaneMain);
            tabPaneMain.getTabs().add(startTab);

            try {

             // Give the controller access to the main app.
            SettingsTabController  controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootLayout2(loaderController);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("xxx" + e );
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            MyLogger.error("Exception MainApp/showStartAnchorPane : " + e);
        }
    }

    public TextField setTextfieldMessage(String Message) {

        rootLayoutController.textfieldMessage.setText(Message);
        return rootLayoutController.textfieldMessage ;
    }

    public CompanyDTO getCompany() {

        return loaderController.company ;

    } 



}
```

Comment: There's too much code to really read through there, but I think the only problem with calling `loadMainStageViews(...)` from the background thread is that you create a `Scene` and a `Stage` there. If you refactor the code slightly so that you just build the root node on the background thread, then display it by creating and assembling the scene and stage in the handler for the task succeeding, then it should work.

Comment: Great tip. But i found the problem. It was because i was showing the stage before all other controllers where loaded. So in the last fxml loader i apply following code :  primaryStage.show();  And it seems to work this way. Now i only have about 1 sec delay between splash screen and mainprogram.